# problema html y css

Tags: html, css, svg

```css
.header__wave{
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="header__wave" style="height: 150px; overflow: hidden;" ><svg viewBox="0 0 500 150" preserveAspectRatio="none" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;"><path d="M0.00,49.98 C149.99,150.00 349.20,-49.98 500.00,49.98 L500.00,150.00 L0.00,150.00 Z" style="stroke: none; fill: #fff;"></path></svg></div>
```

tengo un problema y es que sale la linea abajo y no se porque y tampoco se quita, pero nada mas sale cuando le doy a inspeccionar elemento a cambio si estoy en pantalla completa no se ve la linea

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, sería bueno que pongas tu código para que podamos ayudarte. Viendo tu imagen entendemos el problema pero no es posible resolver tu duda.

Comment: por favor prueba `svg{display:block};

Answer (score 1):

cuando estas en el inspector de codigo, esa linea es una division la cual indica el limite del componente, en este caso tu componente "section" abarca hasta esa linea.

Si esa linea aparece, aun fuera del inspector de codigo, puedes quitarla por medio de CSS aplicando un border:none sobre tu elemento section

Saludos

Comment: muchas gracias xd